# Правила написания слова «гибнуть» с частицей «не»

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, словоизменение, словари

Можно ли написать «чтобы никто не гиб» в смысле «не погибал, не умирал»?

Answer (score 2):

***Чтобы никто не гиб.***

Такое написание корректно (хотя я бы написал ***не гибнул*** или ***не погибал***), частица ***не*** на это не влияет.

[**гибнуть**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x), -ну, -нет; *прош.* гибнул и гиб, гибла
[**ГИ́БНУТЬ**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/38482), -ну, -нешь; гиб и гибнул, гибла; несовер.

**Примеры** из Нацкорпуса русского языка:

*...в одном из ранних «готических» рассказов **гиб** под лавиной; в одном из последних ― засыхал от тоски в полном одиночестве и забвении.* [В. А. Ярмолинец. Подрезка (2007)

*И Павел тоже как будто опускался, тяжелея от пережитого, и казалось падал, **гиб**, но все почему-то не долетал...* [Михаил Тарковский. Гостиница «Океан» (2001)]

*...он хирел и **гиб**, если его с ней разлучали.* [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 2 (1964)]

*...преждевременно вял и **гиб** от холода окружающей среды».* [Ф. Ф. Зелинский. Первое светопреставление (1916)]

Comment: Александр, У Розенталя есть материал на эту тему  §174. Варианты видовых форм http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/61.htm  Пункт 10.  Интересно, что он там приводит примеры равноправных и допустимых форм.  Кстати, непонятно, как делается выбор. И примеров с частицей НЕ нет. Может, это от конкретного текста зависит.

Comment: @Sharon Да, интересно. Пусть живут себе равноправные формы; кому как нравится, кто как привык, так и говорит. Частица НЕ, думаю, всё же не должна влиять. А в Нацкорпусе даже без неё всего 6 примеров с ГИБ. И я, по-моему, не видел и не слышал, чтобы так говорили и писали.

Comment: @Sharon А почему вы удалили последний комментарий? Ссылка, примеры глаголов с двумя формами, хорошие наблюдения...

Comment: Ничего конкретного и определенного там не было.  Колебания в м. роде наблюдаются у бесприставочных глаголов. У Розенталя приводятся примеры равноправных форм, а также допустимых. Но сейчас лучше ориентироваться по словарю и Нацкорпусу (с учетом даты).  Как мне кажется, форма глагола должна быть узнаваемой (не напоминать сущ. или краткое прилаг.), а здесь всё конкретно, да и выбор в паре делается по слуху.  Может, и частица НЕ как-то может влиять. В случае сомнения лучше выбрать привычную форму: никто не гиб – никто не погибал, меньше проблем будет.

Comment: Александр, я сейчас обратила внимание на то, что форма "гиб" часто находится в однородных отношениях  с другими глаголами (хирел и гиб, вянул и гиб) и поэтому лучше сочетается с ними (по фонетике).

Answer (score 1):

Словарная фиксация формы "гиб" есть, см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C). Поэтому никто не запрещает говорить "не гиб", ведь "не гиб" = "не гибнул".

ГИ́БНУТЬ, -ну, -нешь; прош. **гиб** и **ги́бнул**, **ги́бла**, -ло; несов. (сов. погибнуть). Подвергаться уничтожению, полному разрушению (обычно при катастрофе, бедствии и т. п.). (Малый академический словарь, МАС)

Однако стоит учесть, что в современной речи эта форма глагола "гибнуть" встречается редко и имеет налёт образности, стилизованности. Для понимания вот несколько литературных примеров из "Нацкорпуса"; на них видно, что слово "гиб" несёт оттенок стилизованности, который в современной устной и письменной речи может быть совсем не к месту. Впрочем, выбор формы слова остаётся за автором.

*Его взрастили в тишине садов и прилавков, и он попробовал алма-атинскую землю и воду и полюбил их так, что остался им верен навек; он хирел и **гиб**, если его с ней разлучали. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 2 (1964)]*

*Но поскольку эти и другие случаи сами по себе не могли придать рассказу даже мало-мальского драматизма, автор достигал его другим путем: в его первой повести герой топился в ночном озере; в последней ― умирал от рака горла; в одном из ранних «готических» рассказов **гиб** под лавиной; в одном из последних ― засыхал от тоски в полном одиночестве и забвении. [В. А. Ярмолинец. Подрезка (2007) // «Волга», 2008]*

*― Я свободен-с, свободен-с, и нечего вам больше мне об этом говорить, ― опять ответил Висленев, и снова продолжал вертеться, рассказывая Грегуару, в каких он был затруднительных обстоятельствах, как его заел в России женский вопрос, который он сам поддерживал, и как он от этого ужасного вопроса **гиб** и страдал, и совершенно погиб бы, если б его не спасла Глафира Васильевна, самому ему неведомо какими путями. [Н. С. Лесков. На ножах (1870)]*

*Иногда тутор сам оказывался болваном и пьянюгой, и **гиб** мальчик. [Н. П. Гиляров-Платонов. Из пережитого. Том 1 (1886)]*

*«В течение всего года, последовавшего за убийством Цезаря, ― говорит Плутарх, ― солнце было бледно и без лучей; тепло, от него исходящее, было незначительно и бессильно, в воздухе чувствовалась какая-то мгла и тяжесть вследствие недостатка очищающего теплорода; хлеб, отцветши, преждевременно вял и **гиб** от холода окружающей среды». [Ф. Ф. Зелинский. Первое светопреставление (1916)]*